# Pinging multiple IP in parallel and creating list: multiple threads using the same variable (synchronization issue)

Tags: bash, parallel-processing, synchronization, ping

I need to ping a list of devices and store the IPs o the ones that respond for the ping. I have this piece of code:

```
function add_ip_if_pings
{
    ping -c 1 -W 1 $1 > /dev/null
    if [ "$?" = "0" ]; then
        iplist="$iplist $1"
        echo $iplist
    fi
}

# ...

for id in $(seq "$2" "$3"); do
    for nr in $(seq 1 244); do
        add_ip_if_pings "10.$secondIpOctet.$id.$nr" &
    done

done

#waiting for all pings to finish
wait
echo "List: $iplist"
```

So when I print the value of `$iplist` in the `add_ip_if_pings` it does always contain a single ip. Also at the end I get the output:

```
List:
```

I guess this is some sort of synchronization problem because of the fact that multiple threads use the same variable. What would be the best solution here? I need to ping all the devices in paralell, because I don't want to wait forever...

Comment: A command terminated by `&` is executed in a subshell, i. e. as a separate process. Separate processes cannot use the same shell variable, since each shell process has its own copy of the variable.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of adding the IPs to a variable, use the file system. At the beginning of your script:

```
DATADIR=/tmp/multiping
rm -fr ${DATADIR} # Clean up data from previous run
mkdir ${DATADIR}  # Create directory
```

And later in `function add_ip_if_pings`:

```
touch ${DATADIR}/$1
```

At the end of your script:

```
LIST=$( cd ${DATADIR} ; ls )
```